# Cron redirect stdout and stderr to different files

Tags: shell, cron, pipe

I'm using a python script with python-crontab to generate job entries in the crontab, and execute them every minute.

I'm doing something like:

```
my_cron = CronTab(user=getpass.getuser())
job = my_cron.new(command=pathname+'/cron_restart.sh >> ' + pathname + '/log_listener.txt 2>&1')
job.minute.every(1)
my_cron.write()
```

so that the crontab entry will look like (with the correct pathname, clearly)

```
* * * * * __pathname__/cron_restart.sh >> __pathname__/log_listener.txt 2>&1
```

This way, I'm redirecting both the stdout and stderr to the log_listener.txt file. Is it possible to split them, and send them to two different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This way, I'm redirecting both the stdout and stderr to the log_listener.txt file. Is it possible to split them, and send them to two different files?

Youre redirecting b oth to `log_listener.txt` because you specifically asked that stderr (`2`)'s output be redirected (`>`) to stdout (`&1`).

If that's not what you want, don't do that?

`> f` is a shortcut for `1>f` which redirects output (`>`) from stdout (`1`) to the file `f`, truncating it if it exists.

`2` is stderr, so you can just `2>` to some *other* file in order to redirect stderr to a different file than stdout. `>>` is an appending redirection so `2>>` will append stderr to an existing file (or create it) in the same way `>>` does for stdin.

Therefore you can just have a command of

```
cron_restart.sh >> log_listener.txt 2>>log_error.txt
```

to log stdout and stderr to different files.

Comment: Awesome! Before your last edit I was using cron_restart.sh 1>> log_listener_out.txt 2>>log_listener_err.txt...so, the 1 is always implicit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Carlo You can absolutely use an explicit `1` for clarity. It's just that if you omit it then it defaults to `1`.